# Helping using typeOf in a forEach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, typeof

I have been stuck on this question for too long. Here is the question I am trying to answer:

```
//write a forEach loop that loops through this example array and prints out the type of each element

var arr = [{name:'Pedrito'}, ['Banana'],false,34,'hello',null,undefined]
```

Comment: We are not a code writing service. You have to make an attempt before we can fix your problem.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer this is not a helpful comment. I had made many attempts and still found myself stuck. That's why I came here for support and advice. I am new to this. everyone started somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [{name:'Pedrito'}, ['Banana'],false,34,'hello',null,undefined]

arr.forEach(e => console.log(typeof e));
```

Comment: Thank you @wba0. Can you explain where the "e" came from? I'm trying to understand the solution so I can remember it.

Comment: e is simply each element being iterated over in the forEach loop, you can replace it with whatever you want, I just used e as shorthand for element. This also works: `arr.forEach(banana => console.log(typeof banana));`

Comment: @D.Serra The function used in `forEach` receives the current element of the array as a parameter. `e` is the name of that parameter variable.

Comment: @D.Serra It sounds like you need to read up on how functions work.

Comment: @barmar- yes, I am learning about how functions work. I'm only day 2 into learning JS (through a school) so there are many things we haven't covered yet. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
arr.forEach( item => console.log(typeof item) );
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI `typeof` is all lowercase:

```
arr.forEach(element => console.log(typeof element))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
var arr = [{name:'Pedrito'}, ['Banana'],false,34,'hello',null,undefined]

arr.forEach(function(element){
    console.log(typeof element)
})
```

Logs:

```
object
boolean
number
string
object
undefined
```